Convolutional Generative Adversarial Networks Noise Patterns
I am coding a DCGAN to produce Brain MRI data, based on the BRATs 2020 dataset. As a sanity check, I am training on a SINGLE image with CONSTANT noise, to see if there are any inherent flaws in my design. The GAN seems to catch on the general pattern, but there is some sort of noise or distortion.  You can see in the example below, that the generated image is not as sharp as the original.
Original Image

Generated Image after 1000 epochs

The generated one seems to have some sort of "waves" or cross like patterns. These patterns are present from the beginning of the training.
**Generate image after 150 epochs **

** Image at generator initialization **

Here is my code for the generator. The discriminator is a mirror image, with normal conv instead of transpose.

class SimpleGenerator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,out_channels =1,
                 noise_dimension = 100 ,
                 channels= 64         
                 ):
        super(SimpleGenerator, self).__init__()
        self.noise_shape = (noise_dimension,1,1,1)
        self.out_channels = out_channels 
        self.channels = channels
        self.gen = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose3d(self.noise_shape[0],  self.channels * 32, 4, 1, (1, 0, 1)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            self._block( self.channels * 32,  self.channels * 16, 5, 1, 0),
            self._block( self.channels * 16,  self.channels * 8, 5, 1, 0),
            self._block( self.channels * 8,  self.channels * 4, 4, 2, 1),
            self._block( self.channels * 4,  self.channels * 2, 4, 2, 1),
            self._block( self.channels * 2,  self.channels, 4, 2, 1),
            nn.ConvTranspose3d( self.channels, self.out_channels, 4, 2, 1),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )
        
    def _block(self,in_channels,out_channels,kernel_size,stride,padding):
        return nn.Sequential(
       
            nn.ConvTranspose3d(in_channels,out_channels,3,1,1,bias=False),
            nn.InstanceNorm3d(out_channels),
            nn.ReLU(),
            
            nn.ConvTranspose3d(out_channels,out_channels,kernel_size,stride,padding,bias=False),
            nn.InstanceNorm3d(out_channels),
            nn.ReLU()
        )

    def forward(self, x,separate=False):
        
        x = self.gen(x)
        return x



I tried the above code with _block being one or two convolutions ( here we see the two convolutions version). Both results had some sort of noise, which to me seems to have that pattern.
Notes :

I am using InstanceNorm Instead of batch norm as my images are 160 x192x160 they are too big so The gpu can't support batch_size  >1.
The weird numbers you see in the kernel size, stride and padding are because I want to achieve the shape described above which is not a power of two.  Could this be the reason?

